# What is a good approach to install a webserver?

Tags: debian, lighttpd, file-permissions, user-permissions

I wan't to install Lighttpd on my V-Server under Debian.
I'm new to Linux and I wonder if I should install Lighttpd as root or as a new User to avoid security issues?

Comment: A good approach is to start by reading the documentation, rather than just throwing a question into the air and hoping you come out with an answer with zero effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aptitude and all will be installed by itself without you having to worry about it!

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install lighttpd

once it is done go browse [http://localhost]